# tic tac toe game not working (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a tic tac toe game, and I am at the point where the game decides who wins the game. I wrote the logic and all possible winner solutions, but when I play the game, the game announces a winner even when there is no winning combination. What did I do wrong? This is the code pen:
https://codepen.io/xshirl/pen/dmzeMd

Here is my code:

```
let player = true;

$(document).ready(function () {
  const square = $('.square');

  function display() {
    if (player === true) {
      square.on('click', first);
    } else if (player === false) {
      square.on('click', function () {
        $(this).addClass('second');
      });
    }
  }

  display();

  function first() {
    $(this).addClass('first');
    player = !player;
    if (player === true) {
      $(this).addClass('second');
      alert("Player 2 has made a move.")
    } else {
      alert("Player 1 has made a move.")
    }
    if (($(".one").hasClass('first') && $(".two").hasClass('first') && $(".three").hasClass('first')) || ($(".four").hasClass('first') && $(".five").hasClass('first') && $(".six").hasClass('first')) || ($(".seven").hasClass('first') && $(".eight").hasClass('first') && $(".nine").hasClass('first')) ||
      ($(".one").hasClass('first') && $(".four").hasClass('first') && $(".seven").hasClass('first')) || ($(".two").hasClass('first') && $(".five").hasClass('first') && $(".eight").hasClass('first')) || ($(".three").hasClass('first') && $(".six").hasClass('first') && $(".nine").hasClass('first')) ||
      ($(".one").hasClass('first') && $(".five").hasClass('first') && $(".nine").hasClass('first')) || ($(".three").hasClass('first') && $(".five").hasClass('first') && $(".seven").hasClass('first'))) {
      alert("Player 1 has won the game!");
    }
    if ($(".one").hasClass('second') && $(".two").hasClass('second') && $(".three").hasClass('second') || $(".four").hasClass('second') && $(".five").hasClass('second') && $(".six").hasClass('second') || $(".seven").hasClass('second') && $(".eight").hasClass('second') && $(".nine").hasClass('second') ||
      $(".one").hasClass('second') && $(".four").hasClass('second') && $(".seven").hasClass('second') || $(".two").hasClass('second') && $(".five").hasClass('second') && $(".eight").hasClass('second') || $(".three").hasClass('second') && $(".six").hasClass('second') && $(".nine").hasClass('second') ||
      $(".one").hasClass('second') && $(".five").hasClass('second') && $(".nine").hasClass('second') || $(".three").hasClass('second') && $(".five").hasClass('second') && $(".seven").hasClass('second')) {
      alert("Player 2 has won the game!");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the respective HTML and an example where it fails?

Comment: this is the code pen https://codepen.io/xshirl/pen/dmzeMd

Comment: Please include that _in the question_, preferably in a runnable snippet. What situation says there is a solution when there actually isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function first, move the line `$(this).addClass('first');` to the `else` block. So the code will be:

```
function first() {

    player = !player;
    if (player === true) {
      $(this).addClass('second');
      alert("Player 2 has made a move.")
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('first');
      alert("Player 1 has made a move.")
    }
    if (($(".one").hasClass('first') && $(".two").hasClass('first') && $(".three").hasClass('first')) || ($(".four").hasClass('first') && $(".five").hasClass('first') && $(".six").hasClass('first')) || ($(".seven").hasClass('first') && $(".eight").hasClass('first') && $(".nine").hasClass('first')) ||
      ($(".one").hasClass('first') && $(".four").hasClass('first') && $(".seven").hasClass('first')) || ($(".two").hasClass('first') && $(".five").hasClass('first') && $(".eight").hasClass('first')) || ($(".three").hasClass('first') && $(".six").hasClass('first') && $(".nine").hasClass('first')) ||
      ($(".one").hasClass('first') && $(".five").hasClass('first') && $(".nine").hasClass('first')) || ($(".three").hasClass('first') && $(".five").hasClass('first') && $(".seven").hasClass('first'))) {
      alert("Player 1 has won the game!");
    }
    if ($(".one").hasClass('second') && $(".two").hasClass('second') && $(".three").hasClass('second') || $(".four").hasClass('second') && $(".five").hasClass('second') && $(".six").hasClass('second') || $(".seven").hasClass('second') && $(".eight").hasClass('second') && $(".nine").hasClass('second') ||
      $(".one").hasClass('second') && $(".four").hasClass('second') && $(".seven").hasClass('second') || $(".two").hasClass('second') && $(".five").hasClass('second') && $(".eight").hasClass('second') || $(".three").hasClass('second') && $(".six").hasClass('second') && $(".nine").hasClass('second') ||
      $(".one").hasClass('second') && $(".five").hasClass('second') && $(".nine").hasClass('second') || $(".three").hasClass('second') && $(".five").hasClass('second') && $(".seven").hasClass('second')) {
      alert("Player 2 has won the game!");
    }
  }
});
```